# How to compare sets of changesets between 2 Mercurial branches?

Tags: mercurial, branch, changeset

I've got a (remote) Hg repository with a couple branches.  I want to verify that branch A has every changeset that branch B has (it may have more, and that's OK).

Is there an easy way to do this with just `hg`?

I can write a little shell script to do it, but it seems like the sort of thing that might come up a lot, so maybe there's an easy built-in way.

Answer (score 19):

This will show any ancestors of changeset `b` which are not an ancestor of changeset `a`:

```
hg log -r "ancestors(b) and not ancestors(a)"
```

This should show you which changes still need to be merged from B to A if you give the head of branch B for b, and the head of branch A for a.

Comment: This is the only correct way, "a:b" or "a::b" which are often given as an answer do not work reliably. Short form is: "::b-::a".

@Ken: Can you accept this as answer?