# hg log between two changesets of a branch

Tags: mercurial

I working on a release so I need to specify a list of checked in tasks between two revisions of a branch.

This would work on the default branch
hg log -r x:y

But I am not on the default branch, and I cannot find the syntax for specify a branch AND query for checked in between two revisions with hg log.

I think I am missing the obvious here but I don't know where.

Comment: That command should show all changesets on all branches, not just default. You may be looking for the `-b` option to specify the branch: `hg log -r x:y -b mybranch`

Comment: My other question to follow up is, why doesn't this work: hg log -r x::y "branch(mybranch) .  Mercurial returns no results at all, but no error either.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you mean, why does `hg log -r x:y` show the changesets from all branches even if you're on a specific one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare sets of changesets between 2 Mercurial branches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522974/how-to-compare-sets-of-changesets-between-2-mercurial-branches)

Answer (score 11):

Use revsets, e.g. like so:

```
hg log -r "x:y and branch('mybranch')"
```

This should list all commits (numerically) between x and y that are also colored 'mybranch'.

If you prefer topological range (this is what most people understand with the term "branch") instead of simple numerical range, use '::' instead of ':', but check for order of x and y ( x < y ).

Comment: okay, this answered my question. My syntax using revsets was wrong. I needed to use 'and' to specify a branch. Namely if I wanted to only get bug fixes I would also do hg log -r "x::y and branch('mybranch') and keyword('FIX')".  Thanks so much everyone for your help!

Comment: one caveat is that log -r x:y includes x log of x which does not follow the semantics of diff, or git log for comparison. While it seems trivial, it makes scripting with the output much harder. Sigh...