# Mercurial log between two tags

Tags: mercurial

I want to use `hg log` to generate a brief changelog covering the changes of the latest release. Releases are tagged with a "v" prefix e.g. "v0.9.1" or "v1.0". Is it possible with revsets to select a range between the two last tags that start with "v", not including the older one of the two tags?

As an example if I have:

- changeset 0
- changeset 1
  tag: v0.1
- changeset 2
- changeset 3
  tag: bar
- changeset 4
  tag: v0.9
- changeset 5
  tag: foo
- changeset 6
- changeset 7
  tag: v1.0
- changeset 8

I'd like to select changesets 5 to 7, if possible without even specifying v0.9 and v1.0 only using the "v" prefix.

Comment: "two last tags that start with "v"" - do  you really have *another tags*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you really want the answer to the question, "what changed between two revisions" you have to do something a little verbose:

```
hg log -r 'ancestors(relB) - ancestors(relA)'
```

This is different than relA::relB in the case where there was branched development.

Consider the following history graph:

```
$ hg glog
@  changeset:   7:cb998461fc2f
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
|  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:28:46 2014 +0000
|  summary:     Added tag relB for changeset b37a8f32de1d
|
o    changeset:   6:b37a8f32de1d
|\   tag:         relB
| |  parent:      5:187092bb7e9b
| |  parent:      3:2d5af4e62ad5
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:47 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     merged
| |
| o  changeset:   5:187092bb7e9b
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:21 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     more branch work
| |
| o  changeset:   4:dbfe8f003e51
| |  parent:      1:68f933b431ec
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:51 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     branched dev
| |
o |  changeset:   3:2d5af4e62ad5
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:17 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     Added tag relA for changeset 0ad160ab1455
| |
o |  changeset:   2:0ad160ab1455
|/   tag:         relA
|    user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
|    date:        Fri Nov 21 09:25:13 2014 +0000
|    summary:     mainline dev
|
o  changeset:   1:68f933b431ec
|  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
|  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:24:18 2014 +0000
|  summary:     added a line
|
o  changeset:   0:4738f4f68f1e
   user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
   date:        Fri Nov 21 09:23:54 2014 +0000
```

observe the difference between @Kevin's result and the ancestors() approach:

```
$ hg log -r 'ancestor(relA, relB)::relB - ancestor(relA, relB)'
changeset:   3:2d5af4e62ad5
user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:17 2014 +0000
summary:     Added tag relA for changeset 0ad160ab1455

changeset:   6:b37a8f32de1d
tag:         relB
parent:      5:187092bb7e9b
parent:      3:2d5af4e62ad5
user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:47 2014 +0000
summary:     merged
```

versus the ancestors approach, which tells the whole story.

```
$ hg log -r 'ancestors(relB)  - ancestors(relA)'
changeset:   3:2d5af4e62ad5
user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:17 2014 +0000
summary:     Added tag relA for changeset 0ad160ab1455

changeset:   4:dbfe8f003e51
parent:      1:68f933b431ec
user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:51 2014 +0000
summary:     branched dev

changeset:   5:187092bb7e9b
user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:21 2014 +0000
summary:     more branch work

changeset:   6:b37a8f32de1d
tag:         relB
parent:      5:187092bb7e9b
parent:      3:2d5af4e62ad5
user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny>
date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:47 2014 +0000
summary:     merged
```

the actual "greatest common revision" between two revisions seems to be:

```
 ancestor(ancestors(relB)  - ancestors(relA))
```

so a pretty glog of the changes becomes:

```
$ hg glog -r 'ancestor(ancestors(relB)  - ancestors(relA))::  relB'
o    changeset:   6:b37a8f32de1d
|\   tag:         relB
| |  parent:      5:187092bb7e9b
| |  parent:      3:2d5af4e62ad5
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny@sadinoff.com>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:47 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     merged
| |
| o  changeset:   5:187092bb7e9b
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny@sadinoff.com>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:27:21 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     more branch work
| |
| o  changeset:   4:dbfe8f003e51
| |  parent:      1:68f933b431ec
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny@sadinoff.com>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:51 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     branched dev
| |
o |  changeset:   3:2d5af4e62ad5
| |  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny@sadinoff.com>
| |  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:26:17 2014 +0000
| |  summary:     Added tag relA for changeset 0ad160ab1455
| |
o |  changeset:   2:0ad160ab1455
|/   tag:         relA
|    user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny@sadinoff.com>
|    date:        Fri Nov 21 09:25:13 2014 +0000
|    summary:     mainline dev
|
o  changeset:   1:68f933b431ec
|  user:        Danny Sadinoff <danny@sadinoff.com>
|  date:        Fri Nov 21 09:24:18 2014 +0000
|  summary:     added a line
|
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522974/how-to-compare-sets-of-changesets-between-2-mercurial-branches

Comment: It's kind of surprising that there isn't a more concise way generate this reveset, since it's such a common usecase.

Comment: This question does seem to get asked often: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934373/with-mercurial-how-do-you-hg-log-a-branch-with-cross-branch-ancestors/26934547#26934547

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, that *is* more concise:

  hg glog -r '::relB - ::relA'

Answer (score 3):

If you know the names of the tags off the top of your head:

```
hg log -r 'v0.9::v1.0 - v0.9'
```

If you don't, you can find out:

```
hg log -r 'last(tag("re:^v"), 2)'
```

The first log command only makes sense if `v0.9` is an ancestor of `v1.0`; if this is not the case, you can use a single colon instead of `::`, but the result will probably be total nonsense.  In that scenario, you may want something like this instead:

```
hg log -r 'ancestor(v0.9, v1.0)::v1.0 - ancestor(v0.9, v1.0)'
```

That will produce a log of all changes starting from the most recent common ancestor of `v0.9` and `v1.0`.  If `v0.9` is an ancestor of `v1.0`, this degenerates to the same behavior as the first log command.

Comment: you forgot about power of revsets - piping and grepping and tailing aren't required at all

Comment: @LazyBadger: Wasn't sure how to do it at first, but I've fixed it.