# With Mercurial, how do you hg log a branch with cross-branch ancestors?

Tags: mercurial, changelog, revision-history

In Mercurial, I'm wanting to build a changelog of all commit messages for revisions my `stable` branch. Currently, I'm using:

`hg log -r <oldid>::<newid>`

where  is the revision id of the changeset from the last time we pushed out code, and  is `stable`'s tip. This works great for code changes that are only on the `stable` branch, but if I'm merging another branch (such as a new major version which had its own development branch), all those commit messages are omitted! Instead I only get the 1 commit from where it merged into `stable`. I would like some way (preferably w/ `hg log`) to see these as well.

I do NOT want to get any "unpublished" commits in this list - that is, commits on any branches which haven't been merged into `stable`.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:
[image: HG Graph example]

In this example, the last pushed revision is 540. Because of this, I don't want anything at 540 or below. There are several branches out into `default` and back in to `stable`, and I want all of these (539, 541-557 in green). However, there are some changes NOT merged back into `stable` (558-563) which I wish to omit. Pay special attention to Revision 539; it was NOT merged into `stable` when 540 was published, and therefore was not included. But now it has since been merged into `stable`, so I would like to include it!

Any advice you guys have would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this will work:

```
hg log -r '::stable - ::540'
```

I'm uncertain about it because I would have thought the command you provided would mostly be correct, except for changeset 539.  You're not passing `-b stable` to `hg log` by mistake, are you?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do this: you want everthing that has flown into stable (`::stable`) except the things already published `- ::540`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets). Kevin posted the short form of what you want - here's the long form:

```
hg log -r "ancestors('stable') and not ancestors(540)"
```

Revsets are incredibly powerful, and you can just enter them into the filter bar of TortoiseHg.